# hover focus Internet Explorer

Tags: hover, focus

I have trouble with focus in IE. It works in all browsers except in IE.

It works fine on hover, but when I click on the button it stays selected in IE.

```
<div class="controls_toggle"><img src='play.png' alt=''/></div>
```

Here is the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/tu734/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE there must be declared a  DOCTYPE for the :hover selector to work
Just write at top of your page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Then there must be some other css conflicting with this, I am viewing it on IE 8 and it is working perfectly fine with this change

Comment: but there is no other code, I am showing you fiddle demo link, thats where I am testing it, and there it happens.